# Subform not updating from other subform input in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003, ms-access-2010

I have a database with 2 sub forms within a form with fields as below

**Sub Form 1:** 'Qty Booked In', 'Qty Booked Out'
**Sub Form 2:** 'Total Stock'

When running in Access 2003, the 'Total stock' field is updated when a 'Refresh' button is clicked depending on the values entered into the 'Booked in' or 'Booked out' fields. This is done using the following code and works fine:

```
DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acRecordsMenu, 5, , acMenuVer70
```

When I open this database in Access 2010, the 'Total Stock' field will not update. I have tried amending the code to the below, with no success.

```
DoCmd.RunCommand.acCmdRefresh
```

I have also tried the following code with no success either:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

I'm not an Access expert by any means but was just wondering if there is something obvious that I have missed?

Thanks

Comment: Do you think you can share the rest of the form code? Kinda hard to pinpoint the exact issue with just a snippet of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this myself:

```
Me.TblQty.SetFocus
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Me.TblQty_Query.SetFocus
Me.TblQty_Query.Requery
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Me.Recalc
```

DoMenuItem is long since deprecated.